# The time it takes to initilize a Linked list vs an array

Tags: c, linked-list

For a project we have to optimize code to calculate a certain prime number. My question is in terms of time how much faster or slower is it to initialize a Linked list in comparison to an array. Obviously with smaller amounts of data it is negligible however we are working with 100,000,000 different data points so in this case it does make a difference.

Comment: it's not clear whether you want all 100,000,000 million entries in the linked list initialized from the get go or not. If not initializing the linked list is a constant time operation. It also not clear what you mean by initializing an array: Is it just the malloc or is a calloc or something third?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If you allocate ALL 100,000,000 points at once, array allocation is a single, constant time operation.
- For linked lists, if you're allocating ALL numbers at once, then your lookups will be prohibitively slow.
- If optimizing for space : use the linked list, since it will never be any larger than necessary, and deletions can easily free up memory.  If optimizing for time, the array will be faster for lookups.
- If you have to choose quickly, then the array is probably the way to go.  I've never seen a complex mathematical algorithm implemented in a linked list.  Linked lists are usually just good for learning the fundamentals of memory, computation, and pointers -- they don't seem to have much algorithmic value.
- Finally, with collection types, you might get the best of both worlds - the initial time will be small for initialization, but once the collection gets to a given size, there might be a moment where it has to reallocate some new memory.

**Practically speaking**
I rarely find that a linked list or arrays are all that necessary ... Most jobs do alot better with a abstract collection type (i.e. a vector).  But I am surmising that this is a homework assignment... Maybe consider adding that tag to the post ?

Comment: Arrays are also constant time to create. Also, I think he means contiguous storage vs non-contiguous storage, which is the same as array vs. linked list even if you hide them in `vector` and `list`.

Comment: @SethCarnegie yup, clarified.

Comment: If you are working with 100,000,000 data points, an array will be better optimised for size _and_ speed since linked lists need a lot of extra information besides the actual data. It's also misleading to say that arrays and linked lists are unnecessary and then say you can use a `vector` because a `vector` _is_ an array except `vector` can tell you its size and reallocate for you (though you could do it yourself with arrays too), and cleans up the memory for you.

Answer (score 2):

An array will be far far far faster than a linked list to *initialise* (with data or without), but if you're removing and/or inserting data in the middle or at the beginning of the array (very often or *at all* depending on the size), the speed you gained from the initialisation will be lost by moving elements around to fill the holes you leave from removing an item or for making a new hole for a new item.

Answer (score 1):

1) If you initialize your ArrayList with a capacity of 100,000,000 elements, all the required memory will be allocated immediately and the array never has to expand, so it will be faster.

2) With a link list, more memory would be required for the same number of elements, as there is overhead related to the next pointers. So initializing the list will also take longer.

In terms of how much faster is Arraylist, you can do a simple experiment in Java and figure it out.

Edit: I am sorry I assumed it to be an arrayList instead of an array. But, point #2 still applies.

Comment: ArrayList? This isn't C# / Java.